# {{object.image.url}} and {{object.image.path}} show as unknown in template where as {{object.image]} shows the path [Django]

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I dont know what is going on but this is bothering me a lot. As written in the question .url returns unknown in template.

but when i try Model.objects.get(username=1) and print the returned object chained with .url (like object.url) it works and it gives the /media/url/url.png

Model

```
class Consultant(models.Model):
    username= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Avatar')
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

View function

```
 def dashboard(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    user = request.user
    type = User_Type.objects.get(username=user)
    if type.type:
        con = Consultant.objects.filter().values()
        job = Job.objects.filter(owner=user).values()
        conss = Consultant.objects.get(pk=1)
        print(conss.image.url)
        return render(request,"client.html",{
            "con" : con,
            "job" : job
        })
    else:
        return HttpResponse("<h4>Comingsoon</h4>")
```

template

```
 {% for n in con %}
                <div class="ui card">
                    <div class="content">
                        <img class="right floated mini ui image" src="/media/{{n.image.url}}"> 
                        <div class="header">
                            {{ n.fname }} {{ n.lname }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <div class="ui star rating" data-rating="4"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="description">
                            {{ n.desc }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extra content">
                        <div class="ui two buttons">
                            <div class="ui basic green button">Hire</div>
                            <div class="ui basic blue button">Profile</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can we see some code? Model, template, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you're using `.values()` which returns a dict where `n["image"]` is not an object, but rather a url.

In your view, where you wrote the small test code, you didn't use `values()`, so you got an object back where `conss.image` is an `ImageFieldFile` object where a `url` attribute is the path.

Thus the different behavior.

Comment: so is there a way to get both a iterable list or dict of objects and still the .url?

Comment: Either just use `.image` or don't use `.values()` in the query which will produce an iterable queryset where you can use `.image.url`. Unless i'm not understanding what you're asking.

Comment: if I do not use values(), how do i iterate thorough the query set returned by the model.objects.filter() in template?